# AsyncTask onPostExecute never gets called

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but onPostExecute never gets called.

- Created a base class called BaseActivity.java
- From my original Activity I extended this class.
- Placed PostToOpenFeint class inside BaseActivity
- Called it from the UI thread from the main activity my doing:

  ```
  new PostToOpenFeint.execute();
  ```

The onPreExecute(), doInBackground(..) gets triggered, but for some reason the onPostExecute never gets called.

Thank you in Advance!

Dave

```
 private class PostToOpenFeint extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
   */
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
   // does all the work here
   return null;
  }


  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
   */
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onPostExecute(result);
   Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "Done syncing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
   */
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onPreExecute();
   Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "About to sync all your scores", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

---

Looking into it more, this is what I was able to observe. For example if I place this call:

```
 new PostToOpenFeint.execute();
```

right after onCreate of the Activity, then everything works fine. If I place this call say inside a button listener.

```
settingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
   new PostToOpenFeint.execute();
}
});
```

The onPostExecute() never gets called, not sure what I am doing wrong. The restriction I read was to call this from UI Thread and I am calling it from UI thread.

Comment: Please fix your post title: ActiveTask should be replaced with AsyncTask

Comment: Ahh thank you, seems like someone beat me to it.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I have the same problem right now. Same behavior when called from onClickListener of a button.

Comment: Nevermind, instead of calling execute() on the task (like I do for all my other tasks), I called the doInBackground() directly...I don't know how that happened. :-P

Comment: @Bashorings It isn't a good idea to call doInBackground directly it defeats the purpose of an asynchronous task to call all of its methods synchronously from the UI thread

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I had a similiar problem just now. I was extending `AsyncTask<Integer,Integer,Integer>` and my onPostExecute method looked like:

```
protected void onPostExecute(int result)
```

This seemed OK to me, but then again I'm more of a .NET guy than a Java guy.
I changed it to:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
```

because for some reason Java thinks there is a difference between `int` and `Integer`?

I think that your problem is that you're declaring the return type as `void` in your:

```
extends<Void,Void,Void>
```

That means no params, no progress and no result. If you want to execute something when it's done, I think you need to give it some kind of value like and integer or a boolean.

If you change your extends to:

```
<Void,Void,Integer>
```

Now your passing no params, not publishing any progress, but are returning a value. Change your `onPostExecute` method to accept an `Integer`:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
```

Then change the return in your `doInBackground` method to something like:

```
return 1;
```

Then it should execute for you.

Comment: +1 for:"java thinks theres a difference between int and Integer"

Comment: There is a difference between int and Integer. Integer is an object, can be null, int is a primitive, cannot be null. It's particularly important when the function you call returns an Integer and you are mystified by a null pointer exception when you try to store it to an int.

Comment: Just a hint, or recommendation: You can actually leverage the compiler to detect such issues by tagging overridden methods with the @Override annotation. In the case of onPostExecute(int result) it would have shown an error, indicating that there is no such super method with an int parameter.
By the way, Void result values work just as well.

Comment: Also in Xamarin, if you want to pass custom objects or C# objects, make sure to extend those objects to `Java.Lang.Object`

Answer (score 13):

There's one more gotcha about AsyncTasks that I just spent half the day on:

> The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done 
>   automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.

Says the documentation. On Gingerbread (and probably before), given the right circumstances, this leads to `onPostExecute` not being run. The solution, however, is easy, just a

```
new MyAsyncTask();
```

early in the UI thread so the class gets loaded before anything in the background can inadvertently load it.

I had used a static function in my AsyncTask subclass from a background thread that, depending on timing, got called before anything on the UI thread used that AsyncTask subclass, and bingo, a nice Heisenbug.

(Bear with me for answering this old, already answered question, but I didn't find that tidbit of info anywhere, and this is my first post)

Comment: Thanks for talking about UI thread. In my case it helped to find a mistake in coroutine dispatcher.

Answer (score 9):

Note that if you [cancel the task via `cancel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29), `onPostExecute()` won't be called. Pretty logical, but simply overlooking a call to that method had me stumped.

Answer (score 7):

My problem was that somehow I didn't @Override the onPostExecute method correctly. I fixed that by clicking right mouse button->source-> Override\Implement method.

Hopes it helps someone

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the code in doInBackground() never returns?

Comment: I am having this problem and am 100% sure I am returning a valid Bitmap at the end of doInBackground() call, but it's in the GL thread if that makes any difference?

Answer (score 1):

Just Add this to Code to your Activity. Its the problem of Async Task not initializing properly as it is supposed to do.

```
          try {
                Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the parameters in onPostExecute

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
...}
```

Now the method should be called.

Answer (score 1):

Just **return** something rather than **null**, and it'll work!
eg:
 `return "done";`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the proper Parameters in onPostExecute,
 use 
 public void onPostExecute(Boolean response)
{
}
instead of 
public void onPostExecute(boolean response)
{
}
this solved my problem

Comment: I think It should not be `public void onPostExecute` , it should be `protected void onPostExecute` .

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem
what is was doing wrong is that I was trying to write the method in a different scope
the method will only trigger when you write it after the `doInBackground` method and inside the `PostToOpenFeint` class (in this case)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I called downloading a file in UI thread. Then refreshed a token in IO and tried to download a file in UI. Refreshing a token called `AsyncTask` (TokenRequestTask) and didn't call `onPostExecute`.

Because everything was made with `coroutines`, I didn't know where is a mistake. Then downloaded a file in `Dispatchers.IO`, and the problem disappeared.