# Getting always null value async task

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask, bundle

I am passing the value to another activity but getting always null value

```
public class SatelliteDirectActivity extends Activity {
private Intent intent;
private Bundle b;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    intent = new Intent(SatelliteDirectActivity.this,ClsMainActivitySatelliteDirect.class);
    b = new Bundle();
    setContentView(R.layout.initial_splash_screen);
    boolean bCheckInternetConnectivity = checkInternetConnection();
    if(!bCheckInternetConnectivity) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please ensure that you have a internet connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        finish();
    }
    else 
    {
        new GetCountryInformation().execute();

    }
    startActivity(intent);
        finish();
}
private boolean checkInternetConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    // test for connection
    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.v("ERROR_LOG", "Internet Connection Not Present");
        return false;
    }
}
public class GetCountryInformation extends AsyncTask<String, Void,String> {


   protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

   /*   protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        //setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
    }*/
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        JSONObject mJsonObject = ClsGetJsonFunction.getJSONfromURL("http://www.sachdevbros.com/sdandroid/videos/country.php");
        String [] sCountryNames = null;
        String [] sCountryCid = null ;
        try  
        {
        JSONArray mJsonArray = mJsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
        sCountryNames= new String[mJsonArray.length()];
        sCountryCid= new String[mJsonArray.length()];
        for(int icount = 0 ; icount <mJsonArray.length()-1; icount++) 
        {
            JSONObject mJsonObject2 = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(icount);
            sCountryNames [icount] = mJsonObject2.getString("country");
            sCountryCid[icount] = mJsonObject2.getString("cid");
        //  Log.v("JSON", ClsGlobalConstants.sGLB_sCountryNames[icount]+ClsGlobalConstants.sGLB_sCountryCid[icount]);
        }

        }catch(JSONException je) 
        {
            Log.v("ERROR_TAG", ""+je);
        }
        b.putStringArray("cou", sCountryNames);
        b.putStringArray("cid", sCountryCid);

        intent.putExtras(b);

        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Void... aa) {
       super.onPostExecute(null);
        //  showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");

     }
}
```

and receiving this as

```
        final String country[] =this.getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("cou");
    String cid[] =this.getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("cid");
```

Comment: Are you getting a NullPointerException? If so, please post the logcat

Comment: getting no error i am passing this array to to alertdialog to populate list. but list is always empty i tried debugging and at that point the array is null.

Comment: try passing the array in the onPostExecute method and not the doInBackGround method

Comment: Your doInBackground method has return type as `String` then why you returning null ?

Comment: How did you find that the array was empty? Did you log the values? Have you tried logging the JSONObject returned by `ClsGetJsonFunction.getJSONfromURL("http://www.sachdevbros.com/sdandroid/videos/country.php")`. Maybe that itself is empty.

Comment: put startActivity(intent);
        finish();
 these two lines on AsyncTask's postExecute() and run again let me know what happen..

Comment: Thanks every one problem getsolved the probvlem is in async task and also i execute the startActivity in onPostExecute() also Override  the onPostExecute.

Comment: this post help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494720/asynctask-onpostexecute-never-gets-called

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because, you are starting other **activity immediately after start the AsyncTask**, It cause bundle empty, So if possible put your staring other activity code in `AsyncTask's postExecute()`.. Then you can get values in other activity..

For this pass your activity reference in AsyncTask and using that reference call `startActivity()`..

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void... aa) {
       super.onPostExecute(null);
        //  showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
       mContext.startActivity(intent);
       mContext.finish();
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You passing the value in a bundle

```
 b.putStringArray("cou", sCountryNames);
 b.putStringArray("cid", sCountryCid);
 intent.putExtras(b);
```

So you should get the bundle value like this.

```
 Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
 String  mJsonvalue[] = b.getStringArrayList("cou");
```

I think this will solve your problem.