# Uncaught exceptions: AsyncTask never calls OnPostExecute method

Tags: android, asynchronous

I'm trying to check uncaught exceptions in any of my activities.

I put this block code after `onCreate` :

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(
                    new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

                        @Override
                        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                            Utils.logError(MainActivity.this,session);
                        }
                    });
```

`Utils.logError` method writes logCat content to a text file and then upload with a custom AsyncTask to a FTP Server.

This is the logError method code

```
public static void logError(final Context ctx,final SessionManager session){
        StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder(); 

        try {  

              (... code that read logCat  and write to a file ...)

               //Upload result file to FTP with a AsyncTask
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if(Utils.isInternetConn(ctx)){
                            FTPHandler ftp = null;
                            ArrayList<File> archivosAcargar = new ArrayList<File>();
                            archivosAcargar.add(file);
                            ftp = new FTPHandler(ctx,archivosAcargar,session.getCodUser());
                            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);                                            
                            if(ftp.ftpConnect("server","user" ,"pass" ,21)){
                            ftp.execute("upload");
                               }

                           }

                    }
                }).start();

         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
          e.printStackTrace();  
         } catch (IOException e) {  
          e.printStackTrace();  
         }  


    }
```

The AsyncTask code

**EDIT:**

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... peticion) {
        String res="";

        if(peticion[0].equals("upload")){
            if(ftpUpload()) res = "Done upload";
            else res = "Error upload";

        }
        //This print shows "Done upload"
        System.out.println(res);

        return res;

    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

        //This print not executes
        System.out.println("Response " + "/" + response + "/");

        if(response.equals("Done upload"))
        {
            System.out.println("done");
            if(!isLog){ mDialog.dismiss();
            //Toast
          }
            else{
                System.exit(1);

            }

        }

        if(response.equals("Error upload"))
        {
            if(!isLog)mDialog.dismiss();    


        }

    }
```

The problem is that the AsyncTask is completed and the file is uploaded the  `(@Override) onPostExecute` never is called.
I've tried to call `Utils.logError` without a exception and works fine but if I force a exception not works.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't see any AsyncTasks on your code.

Comment: First : where is the asynctask ?

Comment: I've added the summary of AsyncTask code. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494720/asynctask-onpostexecute-never-gets-called?rq=1

Comment: I haven't helped me your answer, sorry. If I launch the log method in for example on onclick event, the AsyncTask works fine but if the log method is launched by the Uncaught exceptions the AsyncTask  not works in onPostExecute

Comment: What is the name of the asynctask class ? Where is it called ?

Comment: **FTPHandler**  and the object is **ftp**