# OnPostExecute never gets called

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a class which looks like this:

```
internal class MyClass
        : AsyncTask<string, int, List<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>>
{
    protected override void OnPostExecute(List<List<Dictionary<string, string>>> result)
    {

    }

    protected override List<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>
        RunInBackground(params string[] jsonData)
    {
        var routes = new List<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>();
        return routes;
    }
}
```

Where `AsyncTask` belongs to `Android.OS`

And find that `OnPostExecute` is never executed.

I have other classes which also inherit from `AsyncTask` (specifically, `AsyncTask<string, string, string>`, but these are working properly - i.e. `OnPostExecute` is called when expected.

What causes this, and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494720/asynctask-onpostexecute-never-gets-called), I suspected this may have something to do with the fact that `RunInBackground` returns a `.NET` type (`List`).

#### Update

After messing around some more I found that this the right way to do this is probably to define the following 2 methods:

```
protected override void OnPostExecute(Java.Lang.Object result)
{
    base.OnPostExecute(result);
}

protected override void OnPostExecute(List<List<Dictionary<string, string>>> result)
{

}
```

Where `OnPostExecute(Java.Lang.Object result)` is called first, and passes `result` into the other `OnPostExecute`, which at some point converts `Object` to the required `List`.

---

#### Original Answer

So I added a second `OnPostExecute` method, which does get called:

```
protected override void OnPostExecute(Java.Lang.Object result)
{

}
```

After checking `result` in the debugger, I could see the values I needed in the `Instance` property, which I can now retrieve with:

```
var propertyInfo = result.GetType().GetProperty("Instance");
var newResult = 
    propertyInfo.GetValue(result, null) as List<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>;
```