# onPostExecute is not called. what can be the proper parameters?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am struck with this issue where, on getting a successful return from doInBackground, the **onPostExecute is just not executed**.

I read [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4701171/1999190) which said that there is an issue with params. But, I am unable to figure out why. I have been running many AsyncTasks but have never encountered a problem as this. And **other similiar SO answers doesn't help** either.

Following is my code. Where I get values successfully in companyVO.
Please help me solve this.

I feel it is something to do with parameters. Even **the @Override annotation on postExecute shows error**.

```
class companyCall extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<CompanyVO.ResultSet>> {


        protected ArrayList<CompanyVO.ResultSet> doInBackground(Void...params) {
            SharedPreferences prefrence = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            String Token = prefrence.getString("token", "");
            try {
                WebserviceImpl webservices = new WebserviceImpl();
                companyVO = webservices.getAllCompanyINfo(Token, getApplicationContext());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Exception", e);
                return null;
            }
            return companyVO;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(CompanyVO.ResultSet result) {
            if (result != null) {

                Log.e("Done", "done"+result.getName());

            } else {
                Log.e("Error", "Not done");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your `onPostExecute` does not have the correct parameter. It should be an `ArrayList`

Comment: Do add comments for negative votes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed `@Override` . So its not the overrided method also you have used different parameters. It should be as .

```
class CompanyCall extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<CompanyVO.ResultSet>> {
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<CompanyVO.ResultSet> doInBackground(Void...params) {
        SharedPreferences prefrence = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String Token = prefrence.getString("token", "");
        try {
            WebserviceImpl webservices = new WebserviceImpl();
            companyVO = webservices.getAllCompanyINfo(Token, getApplicationContext());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Exception", e);
            return null;
        }
        return companyVO;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<CompanyVO.ResultSet> result) {
        if (result != null) {
            Log.e("Done", "done"+result.getName());
        } else {
            Log.e("Error", "Not done");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanku @ADM... but this will then, not allow me to access the getName() method.  in the log of postexecute

Comment: I added CompanyVO.Resultset as ArrayList which solved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your result is Arraylist, Access it with forloop

```
class CompanyCall extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<CompanyVO.ResultSet>> {
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<CompanyVO.ResultSet> doInBackground(Void...params) {
        SharedPreferences prefrence = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String Token = prefrence.getString("token", "");
        try {
            WebserviceImpl webservices = new WebserviceImpl();
            companyVO = webservices.getAllCompanyINfo(Token, getApplicationContext());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Exception", e);
            return null;
        }
        return companyVO;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<CompanyVO.ResultSet> result) {
        if (result != null) {
            for(CompanyVO.ResultSet result_:result) {

                Log.e("Done", "done"+result_.getName());
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Error", "Not done");
        }
    }

}
```